# What are the arguments required to convert or repair an Excel file using Excelcnv.exe?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, msxml

I need to use Excelcnv.exe to fix .xlsx files that are not properly encoded. I have heard that the `-oice` argument may be used.

Microsoft doesn't seem to provide any details on this executable.

Additional Details: Other applications such as Alteryx are unable to open and process certain .xlsx files that were generated by a 3rd party app. They give corrupted file errors. However, I can open them in Excel and save them. After saving in Excel, the file no longer appears corrupted and can be processed. I assume that Excel adds / fixes all the necessary encoding.

I understand Excelcnv.exe can be used to fix the encoding, specifically using the -oice argument.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: could be as simple as 'old-style' `.xls` files being renamed to `.xlsx`.. If you open them with notepad, do the files start with `PK` ? (means it's a zip and _could be_ xlsx) or `ÐÏ` (probably older xls files)

Comment: @Theo -- it starts with PK.

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
# change the path to match your Office installation
$excelcnv = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excelcnv.exe"
& $excelcnv -oice "C:\CorruptedFile.xlsx" "C:\CorrectedFile.xlsx"
```

If that does not fix it, but opening and saving in Excel does, you could do this:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$xlFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\PathToTheXlsxFiles' -Filter '*.xlsx' -File).FullName
foreach ($file in $xlFiles) {
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file )
    # save the file and close the workbook
    $workbook.Close($true)  # $true means 'save the changes'
}
$excel.Quit()

# Important! release the COM objects from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Of course, the best thing to do is to have the application that outputs these corrupted files updated/fixed. Can you contact your vendor about this?